# HTML5 drag and drop: prevent dropping off the edge of the document window?

Tags: css, html, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

I am working on a simple HTML5 drag and drop element. Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4ogxcum/3/

I would like to edit this so that it's impossible to drop the toolbar half way off the page. Is this possible?

In other words, I would like to prevent the toolbar being dropped half way off the page, like below:

[image]

Here is my code in full:

```
function drag_start(event) {
    console.log('drag_start', event);
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain",
    (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"),10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"),10) - event.clientY));
} 
function drag_over(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    return false; 
} 
function drop(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
    dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10)) + 'px';
    dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10)) + 'px';
    return false;
} 

var dm = document.getElementById('taskbar'); 
dm.addEventListener('dragstart',drag_start,false); 
document.body.addEventListener('dragover',drag_over,false); 
document.body.addEventListener('drop',drop,false)
```

;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the toolbar's drag extent by changing your `drop` event as follows:

```
function drop(event) { 
  event.preventDefault();
  var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');

  var x= event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10);
  var y= event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10);
  var w= dm.offsetWidth;
  var h= dm.offsetHeight;

  dm.style.left= Math.min(window.innerWidth -w/2,Math.max(-w/2,x))+'px';
  dm.style.top = Math.min(window.innerHeight-h/2,Math.max(-h/2,y))+'px';

  return false;
}
```

`x` and `y` are based on your calculations, but they are then constrained so at least half the toolbar is always on-screen.

### Fiddle

---

An alternative solution is to simulate the drag-drop behavior by using `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `mousemove`.

In `mousedown`, grab the toolbar's left and top coordinates (variables x and y), its width and height (variables w and h), and the mouse's pageX and pageY coordinates (variables px and py).

In `mousemove`, calculate the new left and top coordinates, then constrain them so at least half the element is always visible on screen:

```
newx= x+(ev.pageX-px);
newy= y+(ev.pageY-py);
this.style.left= Math.min(window.innerWidth -w/2,Math.max(-w/2,newx))+'px';
this.style.top = Math.min(window.innerHeight-h/2,Math.max(-h/2,newy))+'px';
```

### Fiddle

**Code:**

```
(function() {
  var tb= document.querySelector('aside'),
      moving,
      w, h,
      x, y,
      newx, newy,
      px,py;

  tb.addEventListener('mousedown',function(ev) {
    this.style.cursor= 'move';
    x= tb.offsetLeft;
    y= tb.offsetTop;
    w= tb.offsetWidth;
    h= tb.offsetHeight;
    px= ev.pageX;
    py= ev.pageY;
    moving= true;
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup',function() {
    tb.style.cursor= '';
    moving= false;
  });

  tb.addEventListener('mousemove',function(ev) {
    if(moving) {
      newx= x+(ev.pageX-px);
      newy= y+(ev.pageY-py);
      this.style.left= Math.min(window.innerWidth -w/2,Math.max(-w/2,newx))+'px';
      this.style.top = Math.min(window.innerHeight-h/2,Math.max(-h/2,newy))+'px';
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
    if(moving) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
  });
})();
```